# How does the Community bot close questions after just a single VTC?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/305107/timeline#review_178304) was VTCd once as a duplicate, and then promptly closed by the Community bot. Ordinarily one would need four votes for the question to be closed. Alternatively, it would require the voter to possess a gold badge in the tag, which isn't the case here.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the author of the question accepts the duplicate.

See [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes) on main meta.

[image: Image from meta post]

---

It is also mentioned in [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-duplicate-question):

> ### Who can close a question?
>
> - Users with at least 250 reputation may vote to close their own questions
> - Users with at least 3,000 (500 on beta sites) reputation may vote to close any question (see limits below)
> - Moderators may close any question (regardless of their reputation) with a single vote
> - Users who hold a gold badge for one of the question's tags may close as duplicate with a single vote, [within limits that prevent gaming the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310784/377214)
> - If there are pending votes or flags to close a question as a duplicate of a certain target question, the question owner can *indirectly* bindingly close the question as a duplicate of that target (the [Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) will cast the actual vote)
> - The same users who can vote to close questions can also vote to reopen them
> - Users can also [retract/cancel their close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/) by clicking the close button again and clicking the "Retract Vote" button (you can't cast a close vote again on that question).

Comment: Oh there's acceptance involved? I guess I should post bad questions more often, to familiarise myself with the site features I might never see otherwise.

Comment: Yes indeed. Added some more detail to the answer.